# find maximum value in col C in pandas dataframe while group by both col A and B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"RT":[9,10,10,11,11,11,11],"Quality":[70,60,50,60,80,70,80],'Name' :['a','a','b','c','b','c','b'],'Similarity':[0.98,0.97,0.97,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95]})

    RT  Quality Name    Similarity
0   9   70      a       0.98
1   10  60      a       0.97
2   10  50      b       0.97
3   11  60      c       0.95
4   11  80      b       0.95
5   11  70      c       0.95
6   11  80      b       0.95
```

The values in the column `Similarity` has the same group-by with column `RT`

I want to group column `RT` and find the maximum column `Quality` value and group by column `Name`.

For example:

In column `RT` value `11`,which have column `Name` value `c` and `b`, sum each of the column `Quality` values, then get `c = 130, b =160`, and sort the maximum  `160, b`
then get

```
    RT  Quality Name    Similarity
0   9   70  a       0.98
1   10  60  a       0.97
2   10  50  b       0.97
3   11  160 b       0.95
4   11  130 c       0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby with agg:

use lambda to return all Similarities or max to return the max

```
df.groupby(['RT','Name']).agg({'Quality':'sum', 'Similarity':lambda x:x.unique()})

         Quality    Similarity
RT  Name        
9   a     70        0.98
10  a     60        0.97
    b     50        0.97
11  b     160       0.95
    c     130       0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

You may ***not need*** `agg`

```
df.groupby(['RT','Similarity','Name'],as_index=False)['Quality'].sum()
Out[150]: 
   RT  Similarity Name  Quality
0   9        0.98    a       70
1  10        0.97    a       60
2  10        0.97    b       50
3  11        0.95    b      160
4  11        0.95    c      130
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what is the difference between `agg` and `as_index`?  and if I have some irrelevant column,how to keep those column use your method .

`df = pd.DataFrame({"RT":[9,10,10,11,11,11,11],"Quality":[70,60,50,60,80,70,80],'Name' :['a','a','b','c','b','c','b'],\
                   'Similarity':[0.98,0.97,0.97,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95],"samples":[13,2,4,5,6,6,7,]})
`      such as keep the column `samples` along with column `['RT','Similarity','Name']`